# Display the data from SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have designed a Form in VS 2008. I have a database table containing the following fields:

```
Fname (char)
MailFrom (char)
MailTo (char)
Subject (char)
Body (char)
MailID (int)
```

Now I to extract the data from the database and display it on the form in their respective fields.

my code behind is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=PTZ1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = test; Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=sa; Password=sa@; Trusted_Connection=True;");

    SqlDataReader rdr = null;

    try
    {
        // Open the connection
        conn.Open();

        // Pass the connection to a command object
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testing", conn);

        //
        // Use the connection
        //

        // get query results
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr[]);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // close the reader
        if (rdr != null)
        {
            rdr.Close();
        }

        // Close the connection
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

How do I store and display the data on the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the result of the query in memory using `DataTable` for the storage and displaying of that data on `Console`:

```
// Create a String to hold the query.
string query = "SELECT * FROM testing";

// Create a SqlCommand object and pass the constructor the connection string and the query string.
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

// Use the above SqlCommand object to create a SqlDataReader object.
SqlDataReader rdr = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();

// Create a DataTable object to hold all the data returned by the query.
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

// Use the DataTable.Load(SqlDataReader) function to put the results of the query into a DataTable.
dataTable.Load(rdr);
```

OR

1. Definite your custom class, e.g. 'Email` this way:

   ```
   class Email
   {
       public string Fname { get; set; }
       public string MailFrom { get; set; }
       public string MailTo { get; set; }
       public string Subject { get; set; }
       public string Body { get; set; }
       public int MailID { get; set; }    
   }
   ```
2. Read the values in your custom class collection:

   ```
   List<Email> list = new List<Email>();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
       Email o = new Email() { Fname=rdr["Fname"], MailFrom=rdr["MailFrom"],
           MailTo=rdr["MailTo"], Subject=rdr["Subject"], Body=rdr["Body"], 
           MailID=Convert.ToInt32(rdr["MailID"]) };

       Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}", o.Fname);
       Console.WriteLine("MailFrom: {0}", o.MailFrom);
       Console.WriteLine("Mail To: {0}", o.MailTo);
       Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", o.Subject);
       Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", o.Body);
       list.Add(o);
   }
   ```

Comment: can't I use a **for loop** in the `while (rdr.read())` command and display the data?

Comment: Definitely you can use it that way as well. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is almost ready at that point.

Inside the reader.Read() loop you're going through the data 1 record at a time.

To access the columns, use their name

```
(char) reader["Fname"]
```

Now it depends on what you want to do. If you want to store them in your own object - something like this

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

while (reader.Read())
{
MyObject obj = new MyObject;
obj.Fname = (char) reader["Fname"];
obj.MailFrom = //you get the idea
//etc
}
```

If you want to display them, just display them instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        while(rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr["FirstName"].ToString() );//or get column data by name
                 Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(1) );//here accessing column by index
            }
```

U just need to write this